# How to load xml data from browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to load data from browser using URL. Right now I am using javascript for this.

```
window.onload = function()
        {
            // this is URL from which i want to load data. 
            // myURL in this xml file is there. (myURL is running in localhost)
            var url = "myURL&callback=processDATA"; 
            loadDATA(url);
        }

function loadDATA(url)
        {

            var headId = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScript.src = url;
            headId.appendChild(newScript);
        }

function processDATA(feed) //this is function that is called after loadDATA(url).
        {
             // i want my XML file in feed variable. 
             // But this function is not called after  loadDATA.
        }
```

i do not know what to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This function implies that the server API knows to wrap your function with your "callback" parameter for JSONP. Are you creating the server API which is returning the XML as well? If so  you'll need to have it check for the existence of a callback querystring parameter which it would then use to return the data. This is how it would look in c#:

```
if (request.QueryString["callback"] != null)
    response.write(request.QueryString["callback"] + "('" + xmldata + "');");
```

So it executes on return.

If this is a public API find out if they have a specific callback paramater name for jsonp. It is commonly called jsoncallback.